# linux .profile script - error with module load followed by echo

Tags: linux, environment-modules

so I'm very new to linux scripting.  In .profile I just want to load a module and then print out a message to remind me it loaded, but I'm encountering an error when I go about it in that order.

It works fine when I have:

echo "loading oracle/muscle..."
module load oracle/muscle

(that is literally all that i have in .profile)

I'd prefer to have:

module load oracle/muscle
echo "oracle/muscle loaded"

But when I do this and log in, I get an error back saying, "Unable to locate a modulefile for oracle/muscle".  I suppose its some kind of syntax error but I couldn't find anything that really described this kind of error.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that part is working:

```
echo "loading oracle/muscle..." module load oracle/muscle
```

??

I think You should separate command "echo" from "module". I tested your config (Debian 6, I've used "modprobe" instead "module load"):

```
root@ian:~# lsmod | grep loop
root@ian:~#
root@ian:~# grep modprobe .profile
echo "Loading loop" modprobe loop
root@ian:~# source .profile
Loading loop modprobe loop
root@ian:~# lsmod | grep loop
root@ian:~#
```

Above module loop has not been loaded. IMHO it should looks like this:

```
root@ian:~# grep modprobe .profile
echo "Loading loop"; modprobe loop
root@ian:~# lsmod | grep loop
root@ian:~# source .profile
Loading loop
root@ian:~# lsmod | grep loop
loop                    9745  0
root@ian:~#
```

What's more it would be better to print "echo" when module ended successfully:

```
module load oracle/muscle && echo "Module loaded"
```

Kindly please test and let us know about result

Comment: Sorry I've taken so long to respond.... I guess what I'm looking for is how linux scripts work on a basic level.  For instance my initial script: echo "loading..." module load oracle/muscle is really broken up into two lines (which works) but doesn't work when on the same line. then you're fix (with the &&) works on one line but not on two

Answer (score 0):

The "Unable to locate a modulefile for oracle/muscle" error you got is because `module` is not able to find a modulefile called `oracle/muscle` in the modulepaths currently enables.

You should enable the modulepath containing the `oracle/muscle` modulefile prior to load it with the `use` sub-command:

```
module use /path/to/modulefiles
module load oracle/muscle
```